# How to get the first row corresponding cell value if i change the other rows cell value in kendo child grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have kendo child grid. It's having some row. Each row having some cells. If i change the value of a cell  other than first row,i have to get the corresponding first row cell value. That means if i change the second row second column value in child grid i have to get the first row second column value in that grid.

I have written change event of each cell in child grid. On change of any cell value this event will fire. In this event i want to achieve the above functionality. Screen shot is attached.

[image]

Code for change of cell is

```
           $('<input  maxlength="9" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoNumericTextBox({
                    format: "0.####",
                    decimals: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    spinners: false,
                    change: function (e) {
                        //Here i want to get the first row of this cell value
                    }
                }).off("keydown");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do that. You can get the value from the cell text or from the dataItem, which I prefer.

In your `editor` function try this:

```
function(container, options) {
    var $container = $(container),
        tdIndex = $container.index(),
        $correspondingCell = $container.closest("tbody").find("tr:first td:eq(" + tdIndex + ")"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($correspondingCell.parent()),
        correspondingColumnName = options.field;

    // Get from cell's text
    console.log("From Cell", $correspondingCell.text());

    // Get from dataItem
    console.log("From DataItem", dataItem[correspondingColumnName]);

    $('<input  maxlength="9" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo($container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "0.####",
            decimals: 0,
            min: 0,
            spinners: false,
            change: function (e) {
                // Now this is the corresponding cell's value from first row
                console.log("First row's corresponding cell value", this);
            }.bind(dataItem[correspondingColumnName]) // <- bind the dataItem's property to the change event
        }).off("keydown");
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/awASA/2)

Comment: Thank you DontVoteMeDown, but here i am facing small problem with respect to change event. Consider this scenario, in the first cell Thu day column i am having 0. If i try to enter any other rows(2,3,...) for Thu day column, i have to prevent the user.i.e if he enters the some value i have to show alert message and the focused should be the current cell, but for me  on click of other cell alert is firing and the focus is going to clicked cell after removing the alert. How to prevent the user to go other cell. I have tried to use onchange event but it's not working

Comment: @HarshavardhanReddy right. It seems to be another problem so I recommend you create another question with the related code. when you create, send me here in these comments and I'll take a look. Try adding more info possible, even better if you create a demo as I did in my answer.

Comment: raised the new question, can you look in to that

Comment: @HarshavardhanReddy sure I will.